# servlet working on browser but not on eclipse

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am making a simple servlet which get the name and password and return a message to browser.my servlet working on browser but not working in eclipse .
actually it is calling the **NewClass**?user=vibhu&pass=mishra in browser.
and
in eclipse it is calling **Login**?user=vibhu&pass=mishra

```
<form action ="NewClass" method ="get">
---
</form>
web xml
 <servlet-name>NewClass</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>NewClass</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>NewClass</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/NewClass</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Are you using application container like Tomcat or Glassfish? Give some more details plz

Comment: @lwo I am using tomcat.

Comment: @lwo I am using tomcat.   I think there is some problem in web.xml file bcoz i m already updated the servlet name login to NewClass but It is calling the request to Login?user=vibhu&pass=mishra, but in browser like crome it is calling NewClass?user=vibhu&pass=mishra and giving right output

Comment: add web.xml and source code so I can check if mapping is ok

Comment: <servlet>
    <description></description>
  
    <servlet-name>NewClass</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>NewClass</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NewClass</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/NewClass</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

Comment: protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
  out =res.getWriter();
     String name= req.getParameter("user");
     String pass= req.getParameter("pass");
     out.print("hi "+name+"your password is "+pass);
 }